# Git: Fastest Way to Update a Remote Branch to Specific Revision (Haven't Cloned the Repo Yet)

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone, git-fetch

The repo is *very* large, and I'm trying to script a process running on cloud VMs that start from scratch (i.e. no local cloned repo).  Additionally, let's assume that copying a cached cloned repo from somewhere isn't an option.

Is there a way to tell the remote repo to update a branch to a particular revision that *it* already has but you do not?

Otherwise, I have to clone the repo (which takes a *long* time) and fetch using an arbitrary depth (assuming I do not know the depth between the revision and the tip, which is a moving target) until I happen to find it by brute force.

Comment: I mean, do you know the hash of the revision you want to assign the branch to?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell the remote repo to update a branch to a particular revision that it already has but you do not?

Not via the normal Git protocols, no.

If you have some alternative—a web interface, the ability to `ssh` in, and so on—then sure!  You may have to write a bit of code but ultimately it boils down to using either `git branch -f` (if changing something other than the current checked-out branch) or `git reset` (if changing the current checked-out branch).  A `--bare` repository has no work-tree so there is no concern about checked-out branches for those.